# PHP WebService, empty array only with private vars

Tags: php, arrays, json, web-services

Im trying to make this PHP webservice.

on the class "Aluno" as you can see there are 2 private vars.
After struggling all day on this I finally figure out that if I change those vars to public, everything goes as expected. But if they remain in private, funny thing happen, they array is return empty but with the objects, look at the results:

Even though I manage to make it work, I don't understand why It won't work with private vars.

result from webservice with public vars:

```
{
alunos: [
{
_nome: "Fexxxx",
_bairro: "Rexxxx"
},
{
_nome: "Fexxxxx",
_bairro: "Broxxxx"
},
{
_nome: "Ferxxxx",
_bairro: "Grxxxx"
},
{
_nome: "Maxxxx",
_bairro: "Chxx"
},
{
_nome: "Roxxxx",
_bairro: "Cixxxx"
}
]
}
```

result from webservice with private vars:

```
{
alunos: [
{ },
{ },
{ },
{ },
{ }
]
}
```

here is the full index.php

```
    // Helper method to get a string description for an HTTP status code
// From http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/ 
function getStatusCodeMessage($status)
{
    $codes = Array(
        100 => 'Continue',
        101 => 'Switching Protocols',
        200 => 'OK',
        201 => 'Created',
        202 => 'Accepted',
        203 => 'Non-Authoritative Information',
        204 => 'No Content',
        205 => 'Reset Content',
        206 => 'Partial Content',
        300 => 'Multiple Choices',
        301 => 'Moved Permanently',
        302 => 'Found',
        303 => 'See Other',
        304 => 'Not Modified',
        305 => 'Use Proxy',
        306 => '(Unused)',
        307 => 'Temporary Redirect',
        400 => 'Bad Request',
        401 => 'Unauthorized',
        402 => 'Payment Required',
        403 => 'Forbidden',
        404 => 'Not Found',
        405 => 'Method Not Allowed',
        406 => 'Not Acceptable',
        407 => 'Proxy Authentication Required',
        408 => 'Request Timeout',
        409 => 'Conflict',
        410 => 'Gone',
        411 => 'Length Required',
        412 => 'Precondition Failed',
        413 => 'Request Entity Too Large',
        414 => 'Request-URI Too Long',
        415 => 'Unsupported Media Type',
        416 => 'Requested Range Not Satisfiable',
        417 => 'Expectation Failed',
        500 => 'Internal Server Error',
        501 => 'Not Implemented',
        502 => 'Bad Gateway',
        503 => 'Service Unavailable',
        504 => 'Gateway Timeout',
        505 => 'HTTP Version Not Supported'
    );

return (isset($codes[$status])) ? $codes[$status] : '';
}

function sendResponse($status = 200, $body = '', $content_type = 'application/json') {

$status_header = 'HTTP/1.1 ' . $status . ' ' . getStatusCodeMessage($status);
header($status_header);
header('Content-type: ' . $content_type);
echo ($body);
}

class Aluno {

private $_nome;
private $_bairro;

function __construct() {
    $this->setAtributos(NULL,NULL);
}

public function setAtributos($nome, $bairro) {
$this->_nome = $nome;
    $this->_bairro  = $bairro;
}

public function __get($name) {
$name = '_'.$name;
if (property_exists($this, $name)) {
    return $this->$name;
}
}//end getter

public function __set($name, $value) {
$name = '_'.$name;
if (property_exists($this, $name)) {
    $this->$name = $value;
}    
return $this;
}//end setter
}//end class Aluno

class Teste1 {

private $db;
private $alunosArray;

function __construct() {
    $this->db = new mysqli('localhost', 'xxxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxx');
    $this->db->autocommit(FALSE);
    $this->alunosArray = array();
}

function __destruct() {
    $this->db->close();
}

function buscaAlunos() {

if (isset($_GET["nome"])) {
    $nomeParam = '%'.$_GET["nome"].'%';

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT nome,bairro FROM alunos WHERE nome LIKE ? ORDER BY nome');
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$nomeParam);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($nomeAlunoLocal,$bairroLocal);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
             $alu = new Aluno;
             $alu->setAtributos(utf8_encode($nomeAlunoLocal),utf8_encode($bairroLocal));
             array_push($this->alunosArray, $alu);  
    }//end while
    $stmt->close();

    sendResponse(200, json_encode(array('alunos'=>$this->alunosArray)));
    return true;
    }//end if
sendResponse(400, 'parametro invalido');
return false;
}//end function buscaAlunos()
}//end class Teste1

$api = new Teste1;

$api->buscaAlunos();
```

Comment: I tried to override the getter and setter method for the private vars (even that Im not using them.) still won't work.

Answer (score 0):

It want work with private because private vars can only be accessed from within the class. You need to define getter methods in order to return private vars.

Comment: but Im not accessing the var directly, thats why I dont have the getter. json_encode method is probably using them, and its called within the buscaAlunos() function. So shouldn't this work?

Comment: I fotgot to say that i already tried with the getter method in it. Still won't work with the private var, like I said im not using either the vars or the constructors outside of the function.